# Laravel API route Page Expires

Tags: php, laravel

I have a quick question I know it wouldn't take so much time to fix but somehow I don't seem to easily find the solution.

I am building a basic api for a mobile application. I placed by api routes in `api.php`

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/



Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('/v1/meeting/record', 'App\Http\Controllers\Attendance@record');
```

The problem is anytime I send a request to this route it responds with page status 419 (Page Expired).

This is my `record method in the Attendance Controller`

```php
public function record(Request $request)
    {
        return response()->json([
            "message" => "student record created"
        ], 201);


    }
```

I added the `api/*` to the excludes in `verifycsrftoken.php` but it didn't change anything.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: If you send it from blade form - you add @csrf in form?

Comment: I am sending it from Firecamp

Comment: what version of laravel?

Comment: @EmekaOkafor Laravel 8.44.0

Comment: the route will not work the way you defined it.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: make sure you calling the url from api routes and in app > http > middleware try to put your url (route name) on VerifyCsrfToken.php middleware in the array element.

Comment: @PHPGeek I am calling my route as http:127.0.0.1:8000/api/[path]

Answer (score 1):

php artisan route:cache

This has fixed it for me in the past.
Here is a discussion on all of the ways to clear cache:
https://dev.to/kenfai/laravel-artisan-cache-commands-explained-41e1

Answer (score 0):

import your controller at the top of the controller class

```
App\Http\Controllers\Attendance;
```

then define your route as such

```
Route::post('/v1/meeting/record', [Attendance::class,'record']);
```

try this and let me know. thanks

Comment: That isn't different from what I already did. But still tried it and got the same page expired response.